# update ui when all threads are completed vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net code wherein, on button click, i will disable two other buttons and start two threads. Once these two threads are completed i should again enable those two buttons.
Here is the approximate vb.net code:

```
button click()
  button2.enable = false
  button3.enable = false

  thread1.start
  thread2.start

//once these two threads completes

 button2.enable = true
 button3.enable = true
end
```

Comment: I would probably use async / await for this task...

Comment: Doing this from outside the thread will be complicated. There is a ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events you can use to indicate percent done or convey any other info you like.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Thread.Join()` is what you are looking for, but it is a blocking call and will freeze your UI if executed from its thread.

```
button click()
    button2.enable = false
    button3.enable = false
    thread1.start
    thread2.start
    thread1.join
    thread2.join
    button2.enable = true
    button3.enable = true
end
```

However, this is the superior solution because it uses `Async...Await` which doesn't block the UI thread

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Button3.Enabled = False
    Await executeThreads()
    Button2.Enabled = True
    Button3.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Function executeThreads() As Task(Of Boolean)
    thread1.Start()
    thread2.Start()
    thread1.Join()
    thread2.Join()
End Function
```